# Javascript function doesn't returns query result (SQLitePlugin for Cordova)

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova, asynchronous

I need your help to create a SQLite class which allows send a query and returns the result.

I know transaction / executesql are asynchronous and I am trying to resolve this problem.

I wrote this code:

```
function SQLite(pName){
    this.result = null;

    //External function
    this.Query = function(pQueryStr) {
        this.result = null;
        execQuery(pQueryStr);
        //Waiting query result. While is null, sleep...
        while(this.result == null){null;} //This line doesn't work
        return this.result;
    }

    //Internal function for execute query
    function execQuery(pQueryStr) {
        //Emulating transacion-executesql functions with lag
        setTimeout(function(){
            this.result = "my query result";
        }, 3000);
    }
}

db = new SQLite("dbName");
var res = db.Query("query request string");
//As I can't wait for SQL result, 'res' returns null.
alert("External result: " + res);
```

This doesn't work but commenting 'while' line... this works adding this code to end.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    alert("External result (with lag): " + this.result);
}, 5000);
```

My problem: I need 'while'. This make function waits for query result is reported.

Any solution or workaround?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using callbacks or promises the latter is what I would prefer https://www.promisejs.org/ is a good place to start.

In case you still insist on using while (it is bad, because your application will hang until result is back). Your while loop does not work

```
setTimeout(function(){
        this.result = "my query result";
    }, 3000);
```

because this context has changed (more about this here: http://ryanmorr.com/understanding-scope-and-context-in-javascript/), and you either have to declare this property in outer scope, or bind this context

```
function execQuery(pQueryStr) {
    var that = this;
    //Emulating transacion-executesql functions with lag
    setTimeout(function(){
        that.result = "my query result";
    }, 3000);
}
```

also you need to make recursive check instead of while, example:

```
var that = this;
function checkResult() {
    if (that.result == null) {
        console.log('repeat')
        setTimeout(checkResult,1);
    }
    else {
        console.log('success');
    }
}
checkResult();
setTimeout(function() { that.result = true; },100)
```

Comment: I think main problem is one-thread property in Javascript. My app doens't work because execQuery cannot start execution until 'while' has finished. I was looking a one-function solution but I suspect it isn't possible as I would need two functions.

Comment: You are right. That is why i suggest using either promises or callbacks. Instead of while loop you can make recursive setTimeout for not blocking the app

Comment: added an example of recursive check instead of while loop

Comment: Recursive check has same problem as 'while'. I have could solve my problem, partially, using callbacks or events. I say 'partially' because 'asyncronism' + 'unique-thread' have influence over MVC and OOP design. In any case, thanks for your time.